# How to run multiple lines using python -c

Tags: python

I need to use `python -c` to remotely run some code, it works when I use:

```
python -c "a=4;print a"
4
```

Or

```
python -c "if True:print 'ye'"
```

But `python -c "a=4;if a<5:print 'ye'"` will generate an error:

```
File "<string>", line 1
    a=4;if a<5:print 'ye'
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What should I do to make it work, any advice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Enclose it in single quotes and use multiple lines:

```
python -c '
a = 4
if a < 5:
    print "ye"
'
```

If you need a single quote in the code, use this horrible construct:

```
python -c '
a = 4
if a < 5:
    print '\''ye'\''
'
```

This works because most UNIX shells will not interpret anything between single quotes—so we have some Python code right up until where we need a single quote. Since it’s completely uninterpreted, we can’t just escape the quote; rather, we end the quotation, then insert a literal quotation mark (escaped, so it won’t be interpreted as the start of a new quote), and *finally* another quote to put us back into the uninterpreted-string state. It’s a little ugly, but it works.

Comment: Also note that this isn't specific for Python or `python -c` in any way, and will work for `git commit -m` and lots of other commands aswell.

Comment: thanks for this quick answer,but I'm using a tool which doesn't accept line change (Enter key), that means I have to use command formed [python -c 'line1;line2;line3......' ], do you have solution for this ?

Comment: @mario.hsu: You can use this even more horrible construct: `python -c 'a = 4'$'\n''if a < 5:'$'\n''    print "ye"'`

Comment: horrible but useful ,thanks ,but it needs to be changed a little bit  `python -c 'a = 4'$'\n''if a < 5:'$'\n\t'' print "ye"'`

Comment: @mario.hsu: I actually had four spaces indenting the `print` but Stack Overflow collapsed it into one space. Pretend that there were four spaces there and it should work.

Comment: I've tried a few things and only your suggestion of `'\''ye'\''` works, but I have no idea what it's doing / how that boils down to the python interpreter getting `'ye'`.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: I added a little explanation.